# Why is one bone distorting my mesh? Only one vertex group?

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, vertex-groups, distort

Ok, Just following this verbatim https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7p5TIFFC0E&list=PL3GeP3YLZn5jOiHM8Js1_S0p_5HeS7TbY&index=1

And I have no idea why I have my head bone (deleted all face bones to make sure that wasn't problem) distorting the vertices of my head mesh when posed.

[image]

This is when normal (no pose and no distortion):

[image]

As you can see, when the head tiltes the nose and jaw get "dragged" out. Why is this? I went to vertex groups and deleted all the bones from the head except the big head block. Here is the weight paint

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Consider deleting all vertex groups related to bones and starting fresh new work.  Please  state if your work started as Armature with automatic weights.  Do you want organic stretch movement with graduated weights? Or ...Do you want rigid mechanical movement with a weight of solid red implying full [1.0]?  You should click on all bones to see if the another bone has mistakely affected the face.  Automatic weight may imply the cost of rework is small.  For rigid materials only one bone should affect the area, as a concise guideline.  Please clarify these issues in your original problem.

Comment: Please clarify.   I believe I see eyes in the model.  Are you concerned yet the eyes are not moving with the head?  For improvements the eyes must also be affected by the head bone.  It is good that you have images attached.  The images are quite busy and you might use [local view with key /].  We only see half of the face paint.  This problem you are experiencing is quite common.  Again Organic Stretch or Rigid Mechanical movement.

Comment: You can also select the bone group and set all weight to one [1.0] in the vertex groups panel or ... weight paint.  Assuming Rigid Mechanical Motion.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger you're amazing. Is there a way to (because I have like 50+ meshes in this thing) set the weight of ALL meshes to uniform 1?

Comment: I have general answer below.  You probably can correct 50 meshes in 5 minutes.  I would be more concerned for a larger number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the OP has already done manually what the OP needs to do.
You might consider deleting all groups and parent again ... to Single Bone which was previously selected.  Consult a Tutorial Video, one or more.  I am trying to avoid writing a tutorial.

We assume rigid mechanical motion .. so only one bone should have influence.  What follows is a short explanation.  Edit Mode Show Weights is selected.  The bones are outside the mesh only for visibility and discussion purposes. Bones are typically near the mesh.

Below preparing to delete mistake groups.

[image]

When deleting you can delete one by one. You can also lock (the lock symbol in vertex groups) and then delete  all unlocked groups from the menu. Tutorial Slippery Slop ... I mean Slope.

---

Image Below a mistake needs to be corrected,

Correct bone group appears.  Mistake bone groups were deleted.

[image]

---

Image below.
All vertices were selected in edit and the weight 1.0 assigned in the Vertex Groups Panel by clicking the button [Assign]

[image]

---

There are videos on famous video websites that show many of the bone weighting features.  It serves you best to see those because its more entertaining for you and the features are quite numerous so video may be the best format.  There are multiple ways to get something done in Blender.  Single Bone Parent is possible.  Please consult a video. Scripts were not discussed.